# WinCE 6.0 Net connection disabled

Tags: connection, windows-ce

By mistake, I disabled net connection of WinCE6.0 device. Now I'm not able to access the device via Ethernet. I'm using Artila Matrix 604. I can access it through console port, But I don't know how to enable Net connection.

Comment: please tell more about: how you **disabled** the ethernet?

Comment: I was accessing the device using cerhost utility. I Opened Ctrl panel And Internet Connections, I was suppose to change the ip but by Mistake I Clicked on  Disable Tab Is there Any Way To Access Device Through Usb Or Something So That I Can See Wince Os And  Can enable Net Connection

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the device??

Comment: Whether USB serial and activesync enabled in your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I think the network configuration is stored in the HIVE registry, by clearing this will help you to load the default settings for all.